# exception with nvarchar - data was truncated while converting from one data type to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm having a bit of trouble with entering data into several columns of a database, all nvarchar types. I'm getting:

> The data was truncated while converting from one data type to another.  Name of function(if known)

```
DBConn.Open();

cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Employee Table] VALUES ('"+ social + "','" +
        first + "','" + last + "','" + mid + "','" + address + "','" + phone + "',"
            + "'Employee'" + ",'" + city + "','" + state + "','" + zip + "','" + email + "','" + userName + "')", DBConn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid the truncating/converting error?

Comment: Don't do this. Use parameterized queries. Please. Everything else is just asking for SQL injection.

Comment: If you're making a class presentation, SQL injection is much more important.  _Please_ do not train another generation of developers to concatenate SQL.

Comment: Gonna need more information to see precisely what the problem is; could you add the CREATE schema to the question so we can see the detail about all the [Employee Table] columns?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? I can't see that error in `sys.messages` and would normally expect Msg 8152 "String or binary data would be truncated." Are you using `ce` edition?

Comment: I've begun using parameters, but I'm still having trouble connecting to the database. I am using CE edition, is that a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using Parameters

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("Field", SqlDbType.NVarChar)    
Param.Value = Field;
```

Answer (score 7):

Your `NVARCHAR` isn't big enough to hold your string.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the column's length is very short. So the value is longer than the maximum width of the column of the table.